# Debouncing button clicks using Rx

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm trying to make a simple "button debouncer" which will count filtered clicks and display it thru a TextView. I want to filter rapid/spam clicks in a way that clicks with less than 300ms time-gap in-between are ignored.

I did my research and stumbled upon `Rx`'s awesome `debounce()` which in theory should do the exact thing I wanted..

..or so I thought. As the app seemed to only register the first click; the counter won't increment no matter how long I tried to wait.

Here's a piece of my code:

```
    ...

    RxView.clicks(mButton)
        .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<Object>() {
            public int mCount;

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Object o) {
                mText.setText(String.valueOf(++mCount));
            }
        });

    ...
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried to run the thing without `debounce()` and it worked flawlessly (the counter will increment everytime the button got clicked).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Note the following in the [documentation on the debounce operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html):

> This variant operates by default on the computation Scheduler (...)

Or, code-wise, this currently happens:

```
public final Observable<T> debounce(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) {
    return debounce(timeout, unit, Schedulers.computation());
}
```

As a result, the subscriber's callbacks are invoked on that same computation scheduler, since nothing is explicitly instructing otherwise.

Now, attempting to update a view (that's what's happening in `onNext()`) from any other thread than the main/ui thread, is a mistake and it will lead to undetermined results.

Fortunately, the remainder of the quote above provides the solution too:

> (...) but you can optionally pass in a Scheduler of your choosing as a third parameter.

This would lead to:

```
RxView.clicks(mButton)
    .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(...);
```

Alternatively, you can still let the debounce happen on the computation scheduler, but receive the notifications on the main/ui thread:

```
RxView.clicks(mButton)
    .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(...);
```

Either way will ensure that the notifications are received on the main/ui thread and thus that the view is updated from the correct thread.

Comment: It's better to use throttleFirst instead of debounce

Comment: @wilddev: whether it is "better" or not depends on the desired behaviour, as `throttleFirst` and `debounce` do not yield the same result. I originally interpreted the question to require debounce, but reading it again now, I agree that throttleFirst could also make sense. I guess that makes both good candidates. Regardless, both operate on the Computation scheduler, so most of above applies either way. :)

Comment: For "better" I mean that in case of throttleFirst you've got click reaction immediately, but with debounce there is a delay. Just to inform others who will find this question later :)

Comment: True, but since `throttleFirst` is basically a specific flavour of `sample`, it will pass through *every* first item emitted within a certain periodic time interval. `debounce` has different behaviour, because it only emits an item iff a particular timespan has passed *without* another item having been emitted. Subtle difference: timespan vs interval. This may or may not be relevant to a particular use case. Just be aware of this.

Comment: @MH. In RxJava 1.x throttleFirst only uses computation scheduler's time for calculation, but result delivery remains the same as what immediate scheduler does, not checked Rx 2.x source.