# onNewIntent() called unnecessarily without extras

Tags: android, android-intent, android-lifecycle

We have crash reports from our App that we cannot explain. The crash occurs in `MyActivity` because an expected "extra" is missing from the `Intent`. We have extensive logging in our app and this is the sequence of lifecycle callbacks that we see when this occurs:

```
06:04:22.574#a.b.c.MyActivity.onCreate() with flags 0 a.b.c.MyActivity@80773a0
06:04:22.592#a.b.c.MyActivity.onStart() a.b.c.MyActivity@80773a0
06:04:22.596#a.b.c.MyActivity.onResume() a.b.c.MyActivity@80773a0
06:04:23.601#a.b.c.MyActivity.onPause() a.b.c.MyActivity@80773a0
06:04:23.614#a.b.c.MyActivity.onNewIntent() with flags 30000000 a.b.c.MyActivity@80773a0
06:04:23.654#a.b.c.MyActivity.onResume() a.b.c.MyActivity@80773a0
```

We log the object ID (in this case `80773a0`) so that we can tell how many instances of a given `Activity` are in use.

You can see (due to the object ID) that there is only a single instance of `MyActivity` involved here. The `Activity` is created, started and resumed as usual. There are no special flags in the original `Intent` (we log the flags in `onCreate()` and `onNewIntent()`).

Approximately 1 second after `onResume()` we see a call to `onPause()`, immediately followed by a call to `onNewIntent()` and then `onResume()`. The `Intent` passed to `onNewIntent()` contains flags `0x30000000` which is `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` (`0x10000000)` and `FLAG_ACTIVIY_SINGLE_TOP` (`0x20000000`). The `Intent` passed to `onNewIntent()` has no extras, which cause the app to crash.

We have double-checked and there is absolutely no place in our code where we set both these flags in an `Intent`.

We do not understand what is causing the calls to `onPause(), onNewIntent()` and `onResume()` and we do not understand why the `Intent` has this set of flags nor why it does not contain the necessary "extras". There is only one place in the app where this `Activity` is launched and the necessary "extras" are put in the `Intent` before `startActivity()` is called.

The `Activity` in question works correctly almost all the time, so there is no general problem with it. There must be some specific behaviour that causes this problem and we have exhausted our ideas about what it might be.

The manifest entry for `MyActivity` has no special launch mode specified.

Comment: does int happen on variety of devices/vendors?

Comment: @Blackbelt Yes. Crash reports from different devices running different versions of Android.

Comment: Wild guessing the user starts the app again from the app luncher?

Comment: "There is only one place in the app where this Activity is launched" -> Yes, but Android takes responsibility for launching any `Activities` that previously existed when it is restoring an app's state (e.g., after a preemptive termination in order to conserve resources, b/c the app was no longer being used). If I'm not mistaken, it'll send you this `Intent`, in this case. You can recover the original intent using `getIntent()`, as specified in the `onNewIntent()` docs. You should be able to reproduce the problem using dev options -> "don't keep activities".

Comment: Interesting idea however wouldn't kill this the activity so that the instance id would change?

Comment: @rekire I'm suggesting that this process has already begun before the log snippet starts. Note that this is all happening in the space of about a second; the app would've been "killed" several minutes/hours/days ago.

Comment: Is the `Activity` exported - that is, could another app be calling it?  Note that it is exported by default if you have intent filters: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported

Comment: @greeble31 The app has been running for some time before this occurs. We log app restarts (after kills) and that isn't happening in this scenario.

Comment: @rekire No, If the user starts the app again from the launcher, this will only bring the existing task to the foreground. In this case, `onPause()` and `onResume()` are to be expected, just not the `onNewIntent()`. That is totally wrong.

Comment: @RyanMentley No, the `Activity` is not exported. It is highly doubtful that another app would be calling this `Activity` anyway, and this certainly wouldn't be happening for multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

If possible then please extract parts of code necessary to examine this issue because we're shooting blind.

What I can read in [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) is:

> An activity can never receive a new intent in the resumed state. You can count on onResume() being called after this method, though not necessarily immediately after the completion this callback. If the activity was resumed, it will be paused and new intent will be delivered, followed by onResume(). If the activity wasn't in the resumed state, then new intent can be delivered immediately, with onResume() called sometime later when activity becomes active again.

So it seems that your case is exactly matched in that part of docs!
I assume some basterd is calling `startActivity` with flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` twice in a row.

I think this can happen for example if you do `startIntent` from button's `onclicklisteners` - fast clickers may be able to do it twice. Solution for that comes with [RxJava debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32498210/debouncing-button-clicks-using-rx).

Comment: This does not address the issue of the `Intent` flags. There is no place that my app calls `startActivity()` with those flags. This also does not address the issue of the missing extras.

Comment: yes it's not - but as it's not documented it may be undefined behavior - calling startActivity with flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP twice in a row; so those may be undefined results of undefined request